# Is possible to acessing a SSL certified page using Phonegap Application?

Tags: android, ssl, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I know this is a duplicate post..

I want to knew,android or phonegap application is preferrable for an banking application with Webservice to acess the  SSL certified page to acess the private details (account number, Account details etc) ?

1.What are the pros and cons for acessing a SSL certified page (Android Vs Phonegap)?

2.What are security issues?

3.How to resolve this problem?(Guide to attain this goal)

Need some helpfull documentation to clear my doubts...Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to create a custom java plugin for HTTP SSL POST request to avoid ajax POST, and it is worked for me.

[Here is my javaClass](http://codeshare.io/JVBjl)

1 Create a new class say "YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS"

2 In your javascript add this

```
cordova.exec(function(datas) {
    //CALLBACK SUCCESS
}, function(error) {
    //ERROR CALLBACK                    
}, "YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS", ["Your_Password", "Your_Username"]);
```

3 In config.xml add this

```
<feature name="YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS">
    <param name="android-package" value="yourpackage.YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS" /> </feature>
```

Try this, it may help you.

Comment: Basically, using a plugin call to actually make the web service request is your only truly safe option.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can figure out a way to do certificate pinning in PhoneGap / Cordova, I would advise against using it to make a banking application. It might not be too hard to certificate pin in an iOS PhoneGap app, but in Android it would require something like a native plugin to do all of the communication with the web service (basically polyfilling xhr/ajax with native calls).

PhoneGap applications are perfectly capable of accessing SSL (https) web services using xhr/ajax, but without certificate pinning you run the risk of Man in the Middle Attacks.

For most apps this is an acceptable risk, but for a banking application this would be very dangerous.

EDIT: Since answering this, a plugin has been released that handles requests using native networking and includes Certificate Pinning: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

Comment: @ devgeeks I understant what you are saying. Is there any blogs or forum  with  phonegap and ssl implementation ,,,Thank you

Comment: I don't know of any specific blog posts. As I said, if you are just asking about PhoneGap apps connecting over SSL/TLS https connections, that's no different then any other AJAX/XHR connection to an https endpoint. However, if you are talking about certificate pinning or client certificate authentication, that is another story entirely. As I said, I had to polyfill $.ajax with a native https connection to achieve client cert authentication and cert pinning so far. Though the problem is Android. I believe it's possible on iOS with a plugin.

Comment: I have edited my comment to include a relatively new plugin that allows network requests to use Certificate Pinning.

Answer (score 1):

I recently released a cordova app using the ionic framework, which connects to a Django server running a REST framework. Because we were using auth tokens SSL was essential.

I didn't have any issue getting my cordova app to connect to the SSL server simply by forcing all of my  tags to use `https://` instead of `http://`.

Honestly, there isn't a great reason not to use SSL outside of ease of setup and the cost of a signed certificate.

As an aside, there is no need for a complicated java plugin for this. AJAX over https works just fine out of the box with a standard XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: There is a need if you want to avoid the man in the middle attack, and on a banking app you should avoid the man in the middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for certificate checking for iOS and android https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

1.What are the pros and cons for acessing a SSL certified page (Android Vs Phonegap)?
If you just access to a SSL certified page, it's the same doing it from android or from phonegap, you can still get man in the middle attacks.

2.What are security issues?
man in the middle attacks

3.How to resolve this problem?(Guide to attain this goal)
Checking the certificate everytime you try to connect with the server, in phonegap you can use the plugin I told you, on android you do it natively.

Comment: @jcesar.. Thanks for your information. for avoiding the man in middle attack,we are using SSL certification and made this https://.... isin't??

Comment: no, using SSL and https connections isn't enough to avoid man in the middle attacks, the 'hacker' can offer free wifi and install a self signed certificate, then your app thinks it's connecting to your server, but it is connecting to the hacker computer and he can see the data. You have to do the certificate pinning or checking to see if the certificate used by the server you are connecting to is the one that should be, comparing the certificate directly or the certificate fingerprint

Comment: The problem with Eddy's plugin is that it only checks the cert while you are checking the cert ;) you then have to make a *second* call to the server to make the API request. A sufficiently advanced attacker could allow the first request to pass through while intercepting subsequent requests, etc.

Comment: You are right, but I think it could be easily converted to a plugin that checks the certificate and do the get/post if the server is valid